# How to change observable complex object?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In rxjs I want to change property in complex object BUT CHANGE NOTHING ELSE.

For example:

I have User Class:

```
class User {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public role: string
    ) { }
}
```

My Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    user: BehaviorSubject<User>;

    constructor() {
        this.user = new BehaviorSubject(
            new User('wizardnet', 'admin')
        );
    }

    setRole(role) {
        // change ONLY the Role property of this.user ???????
        // subscribe then clone the object and then call next() ??
    }
}
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you got it all correct except that you don't need to subscribe to get the value of the user in your service. You can just use `.value`:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    user: BehaviorSubject<User>;

    constructor() {
        this.user = new BehaviorSubject(
            new User('wizardnet', 'admin')
        );
    }

    setRole(role) {
        const updateUser = Object.assign(this.user.value, {role: role});
        this.user.next(updateUser);
        return this.user.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect! I missed the .value :)

Comment: @ShlomiLevi beauty of `BehaviorSubject` :)

Comment: doesn't this leave the code open to race conditions?

Comment: @IcedDante it's up to the developer to take care of the atomicity of the data. the point of this answer though, is to showcase that `BehaviourSubject` has the ability to retain a previous value, which was set through the `.next()` method

Comment: So in other words, yes! this does open up the code to race conditions and should (IMO) be avoided